# DOS DIGITOS PARA LA FECHA EN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, date

BUEN DIA

estoy generando un codigo unico de un producto para un lote pero solo necesito los dos ultimos digitos del año y si el dia o el mes pasa a 1,2,3,4 etc..  tenga este formato  01,02,03 etc este es mi codigo

lo que quiero es AG2012281 en ejemplo del dia de hoy   gracias a la persona que me colabore

```js
let miFechaActual= new Date();
let dia = miFechaActual.getDate();
let mes = parseInt(miFechaActual.getMonth())+1;
let ano = miFechaActual.getFullYear();
let turno = miFechaActual.getHours();

      if (turno>=5 && turno<13) {
        turno=1;
      } else if (turno>=13 && turno<21) {
        turno=2;
      } else if (turno>=21 && turno<5) {
        turno=3;
      }

       $("#lote").val(`AG ${ano}${mes}${dia}${turno}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="lote">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Obtener dos últimas letras

Puedes utilizar `slice()`

```
let año = new Date().getFullYear().toString(); // getFullYear() retorna un número, para poder usar slice() necesitamos convertirlo a un string utilizando toString()
let final = año.slice(-2);
console.log(final);
```

### Interpretando la operación en tu caso

Podemos obtener el mes actual con el siguiente código

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
const mes = monthNames[new Date ().getMonth()].substring(0,2);

// Obtendremos el nombre del día de hoy
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const dia = days[new Date().getDay()].substring(0, 2); // Obtener dos primeras letras

// Obtener el año
const año = new Date().getFullYear().toString(); // getFullYear() retorna un número, para poder usar slice() necesitamos convertirlo a un string utilizando toString()
const finalAño = año.slice(-2);

const finalNombre = mes+dia+finalAño;
console.log(finalNombre);
```

#### Interpretando todo en mayúsculas

Usa toUpperCase() para convertir todo el string a mayúsculas

```
console.log(finalNombre.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: gracias si me funciono :)